# Get metaclass type in C++

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, metaclass

### Background

In his [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0707r0.pdf) and also the [CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/80BZxujhY38), Herb Sutter suggests adding Metaclasses to C++. That enables the users to have a lot more flexibility in terms of creating and enhancing new types during the compilation time. One of the examples in the proposal is the creation of the `interface` metaclass or `the plain-struct` metaclass.

In the current implementation of the C++ there are three keywords for declaring types: `class`, `struct`, and `enum`.

Imagine that we've created a new metaclass `plain_struct` that enables us to write code like

```cpp
plain_struct User {
    string name;
    string surname;
};
```

And later on we can have a function or a class-method that accepts a template parameter like

```cpp
template <typename T>
void printUser(T user) {
     cout << user.name << " " << user.surname << endl;
}
/* 
   ...
*/
User u("N", "S");
printUser(u);
```

### The question

Is there a way of overloading this function or somehow detecting at runtime if the object passed to the function `printUser` is of metaclass `struct`/`class` or the custom-defined `plain_struct`.

For instance, is it possible to have something like this (the following code is more like a pseudocode not an actually working one)?

```cpp
template <class T>
void printUser(T user) {
     cout << "User is of metaclass class";
}
template <plain_struct T>
void printUser(T user) {
     cout << "User is of metaclass plain_struct";
}
/* 
   ...
*/
User u("N", "S");
printUser(u);  // prints "User is of metaclass plain_struct"
```

Comment: The meta-class proposal is still in its infancy. There is little to no wording, and it very likely won't even *be* in C++20 (Herb says as much in the talk). There is no way to *answer* your question, because the feature you ask about doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks for the clarification. Some compilers have already started supporting metaclasses and I was wondering if this kind of feature is/will be available

Comment: I believe you are referring to the POC in Clang on godbolt? That is for exposition purposes, to demonstrate the proposal has (much) merit. But ultimately, the expected behavior and its nuances will be determined by wording in the published ISO C++ standard. That wording doesn't exist yet, not even in the proposal itself. You can see the updated proposal for yourself, too http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0707r3.pdf

Comment: This is *not* going to be a feature in c++20, by the way.   It isn't even being attempted to be included.

Comment: @Martin You may not even get it in C++23...